# Can i upload images to Facebook or Twitter Via App Inventor app?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have an idea to make an app with AI which can upload an image taken using the camera app or image picker to a profile in FB or Twitter. Any help would be of great use.

The twitter one can be done using the twitter component...If u guys could help me out with the Facebook one! It would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it's possible.  If you can do it, you're going to have to use the Activity Starter.  One way to do this is to use the SEND intent, which will ask you to choose an app to share your data.  See this thread for a discussion on it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appinventor/OMWG2gigLa0

I have not found any Facebook-specific intents that you can call.  The thing you have to know is that while there are some standard intents in Android that multiple apps use "Like SEND", any app can create its own intent, and it's possible Facebook has done so.  Do searches for programming this in Android to get a hint of what to do.

Just note that when they say "Intent.setAction", that's what you'd put into your Activity Starter.

One more thing: Facebook allows you to upload a photo to your profile by emailing it.  It may be easier to tell AppInventor to send an email.  See this link for instructions: https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook/share-photos-and-videos-anywhere-you-have-email/109768117130